# Execute HTTP request

Tags: php

I want to get the response of a url, say http://www.google.com using the following code:

```
$fp = @fopen("http://www.google.com/", "r");
```

but it is always returning false.
I've also tried this:

```
@file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/");
```

with no hope. 
Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: What is your `allow_url_fopen` ini setting?

Comment: I'd disable the error suppression (remove the `@` before those functions) and make sure that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in your php.ini file.  Let us know what the generated errors are once you've done that.

Comment: Please remember that Google Rules prohibits downloading search results via CURL etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents()` for HTTP requests, but you have to ensure to correctly set the proper stream context.

Look at this code (taken from PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)):

```
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/', false, $context);
```

This should work, even if the better way to perform a HTTP request in PHP is for sure using cURL extension, like many others suggested in this thread.

Comment: Huh, never knew about the stream context thing.  Gonna tuck that away next time I need to set a User-Agent and don't want to cURL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cURL to retrieve html like this

```
        function get_html($url){
            /**
            * Initialize the cURL session
            */
            $ch = curl_init();
            /**
            * Set the URL of the page or file to download.
            */
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            /**
            * Ask cURL to return the contents in a variable
            * instead of simply echoing them to the browser.
            */
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            /**
            * Execute the cURL session
            */
            $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
            /**
            * Close cURL session
            */
            curl_close ($ch);

            return $contents;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening a URL using standard file functions only works if the configuration flag `allow_url_fopen` is set.  That's a system-level setting, so you will probably need to edit your php.ini to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to use curl http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

It also may be your software firewall that is blocking php from making http connections.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small HTTP client library that is independet from PHPs modules. It comes bundled in the videodb.net php package and includes caching mechanisms, HTTP 1.0/1.1, proxy support etc. Check the core/httpclient.php if interested.